# Access direct column value in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I've just spotted a bug in some piece of code. There is an SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1
FROM TAB
ORDER BY COL1 DESC
```

Now, **COL1** value format returned looks like this:

```
17 Sep 2001
07 Mar 2011
```

and values stored in database look like this:

```
2011-03-07 00:00:00
2001-09-17 00:00:00
```

But because ORDER BY clause uses

```
17 Sep 2001
07 Mar 2011
```

values, ordering is incorrect. As I cannot change column names (there's large dependency between query and application that uses it), I have to modify & fix the SQL statement to return rows with correct ordering. Is there any way to modify it in a way that ORDER BY clause uses real value stored in row's column instead of converted one? I tried :

```
ORDER BY TAB.COL1 DESC
```

but it also didn't work.

Thanks,Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want sorting before converting value then try this :

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),COL1,106) as COL1 
FROM        TAB 
ORDER BY    COL1 DESC
```

or if you want sorting after converting value then try this :

```
SELECT convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1 
FROM TAB 
ORDER BY convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) DESC
```

Comment: The op wants to order by the original value, not the converted value I think

Comment: Your idea was good, I've changed format code to 120 (returns date in sortable format). Now clause looks like this: ORDER BY CONVERT(nvarchar(11), COL, 120) DESC , and result is as I expected. Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised if your first query does work with no name for the derived table and using `ORDER BY` in a subquery, certainly doesn't work in supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @onedaywhen : now check my answer. I think there is no need of subquery to sort by original column

Comment: OK, in the meantime I tested on a MSSQL2000 server and the ORDER BY indeed caused an error so it was right to edit it away ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could just change the alias name of your field to something other than `COL1`, that should cause the ORDER BY to go on the field itself and not the computed alias:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1_ALIAS
FROM TAB
ORDER BY COL1 DESC
```

**UPDATE**

If the column name needs to stay the same try this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1, COL1 AS COL1_ORIGINAL
FROM TAB
ORDER BY COL1_ORIGINAL DESC
```

Comment: I can't change do it cos application that uses that query works on column names, so COL1 must stay

Comment: +1 the second query looks good: it is good practice to expose the sort order column to the caller anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

You should qualify your column name with table name

```
ORDER BY TAB.COL1 DESC
```

Try this

```
create table TAB(Col1 datetime)

insert into TAB values (getdate())
insert into TAB values (getdate()+323)

SELECT convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1
FROM TAB
ORDER BY TAB.COL1 DESC

SELECT convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1
FROM TAB
ORDER BY COL1 DESC
```

Result on SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005:

```
COL1
-----------
04 Aug 2012
16 Sep 2011

(2 row(s) affected)

COL1
-----------
16 Sep 2011
04 Aug 2012

(2 row(s) affected)
```

This does not work for SQL Server 2000 so here is a workaround for that if you really need the column name to be the same as the alias.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1
FROM TAB
ORDER BY convert(datetime, COL1) DESC
```

**Edit**
It will also not work in version later that SQL Server if you have Compatibility Level SQL Server 2000(80). In that case I suggest you change compatibility level.

Comment: @dragonfly  - Do you use SQL Server 2000? It does not work on SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Thanks for effort though :)

Comment: Unfortunately there was a bug in SQL Server 2000 regarding ORDER BY. See the last item in this discussion thread: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.clients/browse_thread/thread/d470c3452e700844/4c477c2276bcf6fa?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=order+by+fixed+garbage+sql+2000+skass#4c477c2276bcf6fa

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT  convert(varchar(11),COL1,106) as COL1
FROM    (SELECT      COL1
         FROM        TAB
         ORDER BY    COL1 DESC)
```

This will basically order the result before throwing it into the convert method.

Answer (score 0):

Double renaming:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(11), COLX, 106) AS COL1
FROM  
     ( SELECT COL1 AS COLX
       FROM TAB
     ) tmp
ORDER BY COLX DESC
```